# Is there a way to send updates from PHP to flash in the middle of a request?

Tags: php, flash, urlrequest

I have a PHP process that does a bunch of stuff and I want to send feedback to the Flash client that calls it, as the request is being processed. However, since I'm listening for the COMPLETED event, I don't get the feedback until the PHP completes execution (at which time all the buffered messages arrive at once).

I tried using the PROGRESS event but that seems not to work (unless I'm not using it right).

Is there something to this on the PHP side that I may be missing? Or is Flash simply not designed to get updates from the server in a regular URLRequest... I can use a socket for this, but I would much rather not have to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. Key is **flash.net.URLStream**. 
I'm using it this way, (code is not complete but I think you get the picture):

```
var stream:URLStream = new URLStream();
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("yourUnbufferedPHPURLhere?rand="+Math.random());
stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
stream.load(request);
function progressHandler(event:Event):void{
    trace("PROGRESS: "+stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are asking PHP to do on the backend.  If you are sending json or xml data you could always call `flush` to send the current output buffer to the client on a more frequent basis.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the PROGRESS event while using PHP's [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php%20flush%28%29)  function to send output periodically, rather than when the PHP script finishes execution.

Comment: actually... I think I gave the green checkmark prematurely. The PROGRESS with the flush does provoke an event, but there is no data that is returned.  I think this may be a php issue, though the docs do seem to indicate that the progress event isn't designed to return back data... rather just a byte size.